# Philadelphia Sitecore User Group:

Tags: discussion, community-event

- **Date/Time (local):** Wednesday, 30 August 2017 *at 6:00pm*
- **Date/Time (UTC):** Wednesday, 30 August 2017 *at 10:00pm*
- **Location:** Delphic Digital, 10 Shurs Ln, STE 201, Philadelphia, PA 19127
- **Event Details:** [Meetup Details and RSVP](https://www.meetup.com/)
- **Contact:** @zachary_kniebel (Sitecore Community Slack)
- **Description:** The Philadelphia Sitecore Community is pleased to welcome Jason Wilkerson (@longhorntaco) for a sneak peak into xConnect and how you can leverage this natively omni-channel platform to assemble a richer picture of your customer in xDB and continue to revolutionize how you serve those who interact with your brand!

Comment: Wow. While we don't have a formal notice period for these; I would advise more than 24 hours advance notice :-)

Comment: Yeah, it was last minute. No worries.